# In AureliaJS, how to add/remove views from JS instead of markup?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have several views/components that implement custom elements, so I use them in my markup as follows:

```
  <require from="./panels/property_inspector/PropertyInspector"></require>
  <property-inspector--panel></property-inspector--panel>
```

So far so good. But now I need to add/remove these kind of views/components programmatically. I was reading the aurlia hub, but I wasn't successful... Any hint appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish exactly. Based on the very short question without any real example of what you are trying to do, maybe you want [compose](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/4)?

Comment: try to use model to drive the view, instead of manual add/remove. Use if binding to add/remove dom, use show binding to toggle display: none/block. http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/8

Comment: We need more information about your specific task in order to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, I agree with @peinarydevelopment that `compose` may be of use to you.  [See compose documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/4)

You can use a `<compose>` element and bind the `view-model` attribute to a property on your view model.  This property should specify the path to the view model or an actual instance of a view model that has been imported.

**Example:**

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <h2>dynamic view model by path</h2>

  <button click.trigger="loadNewViewModel()">Load different vm</button>

  <compose view-model="${currentViewModel}"></compose>

</template>
```

*app.js*

```
export class App {

  currentViewModel = "test.js";

  loadNewViewModel(){
    this.currentViewModel = "new.js"
  }
}
```

**See this gist:**
https://gist.run/?id=a2f17028d45ea202cd19be5491272dde